# Interpreting gradient and performance results in neural artificial networks trainning with Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am training a neural network in Matlab and I am having some trouble to understand the obtained results.

For example, Matlab apresents in the nntraintool the Performance and Gradient values obtained in the training phase.

If I understood it well, we want the smallest performance as possible, that is, the performance value should be close to the net.trainParam.goal=0.001 parameter.

But, I do not know how to interprete the gradient value. We want the smallest or biggest possible value?

Supposing a MLP network with a hidden layer with 20 neurons (scenario 1.a). The dataset is the 
thyroid_dataset. The code is the following:

```
[InputData,TargetData] = thyroid_dataset;

net = newff(InputData,TargetData,20 ,{'logsig' 'tansig'},'traingd');

net.trainParam.epochs=20000;
net.trainParam.goal=0.001;
net.trainParam.lr=0.05;
net.divideParam.trainRatio=0.7;
net.divideParam.valRatio=0;
net.divideParam.testRatio=0.3;

[net,tr] = train(net,InputData,TargetData);

OutputData = net(InputData);
errors = gsubtract(TargetData, OutputData);
performance = perform(net, TargetData, OutputData);
```

Suppose, as well, that a new hidden layer with 20 neurons was add, so the new MLP is (scenario 1.b):

```
net = newff(InputData,TargetData,[20 20],{'logsig' 'logsig' 'tansig'},'traingd');
```

Then, I runned the both scenarios and I have obtained the following results:

```
 Scenario 1.a
 Gradient: 0.00111 / Performance: 0.00443 / Epoch: 20000


 Scenario 1.b
 Gradient: 0.00070 / Performance: 0.04460 / Epoch: 20000
```

Which scenario is the best?

Now, lets suposse the learning algorithms were changed. In scenario 2.a we have  Levenberg-Marquardt, and in scenario 2.b we have Gradient descent with adaptive learning rate backpropagation.

The results were:

```
Scenario 2.a
Gradient: 3.14e-08 / Performance: 0.00205 / Epoch: 174


 Scenario 2.b
 Gradient: 3.08e-08 / Performance: 0.04580 / Epoch: 212
```

In the scenarios 2.a and 2.b the epoches were much more smaller than in scenarios 1.a and 1.b. Moreover, the gradients were smaller as well.

What do it mean?

Scenarios 2.a and 2.b are better than 1.a and 1.b? Or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Gradient methods which used for training neural network are based on gradient.

What does it means? These methods use gradient for moving in solution space. When they move in solution space, their values will changes, because gradient is different in each points of solution space.

There is any relation between gradient and performance.